# Is this combinatorial problem for noncommutative variables known?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that I have two non-commutative variables $a,b$. Then the number of different strings  given by $(a+b)^n$ is $2^n$ and their lenght is $n$. Let me choose $n=5$. I can write
$$
(a+b)^5=[a^5]+[a^4b]+[a^3b^2]+[a^2b^3]+[ab^5]+[b^5],
$$
where $[a^p b^q]$ denotes an equivalence class of strings with $p$ number of $a$'s and $q$ number of $b$'s. The number of elements in the above six classes is obviously $1,5,10,10,5,1$. To be clear what I want to calculate, let me take the class $[a^3b^2]$ and write all its elements:
$$
aaabb\\
aabab\\
abaab\\
baaab\\
aabba\\
ababa\\
baaba\\
abbaa\\
babaa\\
bbaaa.
$$
Here is the question. What is the number of strings, where when I go symbol by symbol from the right and count the number of $a$'s and $b$'s, I will *always* (ie at every step) have the number of $b$'s smaller or equal to the number of $a$'s?

So what happens with $[a^3b^2]$? After the first step the first four sequences are gone since they all start with $b$ (one $b$ and zero $a$). Six remains after the second step because they contain either $ba$'s (one $a$ and one $b$) or $aa$'s. After the third step $aabba$ is gone (two $b$'s and one $a$) and that's the last one excluded because in the last two steps before arriving to the left, the accumulated number of $b$'s is always lower than $a$'s. So the answer is 5 strings remain.

Is there an expression for all classes of $(a+b)^n$ for an arbitrary $n$? Note that all classes where the number of $b$'s is greater than the number of $a$'s will not contribute to the counting (so in our example $[a^2b^3],[ab^5],[b^5]$) do not contribute with any sequence. What makes this task complicated is that if the number of $b$'s is less, they still can 'locally' outnumber the number of $a$'s to their right (like the $aabba$ string).

Comment: It is a version of the Bertrand ballot problem.

Comment: When the number of $a$s is the same as $b$s, this is the parentheses balancing question, which is computed by the Catalan Numbers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number When there are more $b$s than $a$s, it is more complicated.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh wow, so looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem is the answer ${m+1\over{n+m\over 2}+1}{n\choose(n+m)/2}$, where $m=p-q$ and $n$ the same? It gives five indeed.

Comment: Binomial(n, floor(n/2)) -> https://oeis.org/A001405 has description well fitting your problem: it is also the number of distinct strings of length n, each of which is a prefix of a string of balanced parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is what is known as the Bertrand Ballot problem. the formula is given by

$$\frac{m+2}{\frac{n+m}{2}+1}\binom{n}{\frac{n+m}{2}}$$

where $m=p−q$ and $n$ is the same

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem) for details.

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't this be written by AndréNicolas ?

Comment: I waited half an hour. He didn't so I figured I'd give you an opportunity to close the question

Comment: Ok but he doesn't get points/reputation, no?

Comment: Correct, though that's not the point of the site...

Comment: I am happy with the outcome, OP has the answer, with link.

Comment: Ok accepted with the moral credit going to @AndréNicolas